# C#: Defining a Delegate that Takes N Boolean args, to extract argument names later

Tags: c#, delegates, metaprogramming

I'm working on a personal project to build a Truth Table Generator, with an emphasis on collecting/cementing what I'm learning about logical equivalence.

As such, I'm trying to write it in such a way that it takes a *C# Function* as an argument. I'll turn it into a ["build a compiler project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084873/how-can-i-build-a-truth-table-generator) later, but for now I want to learn more about delegates, metaprogramming, and have fun with logical equivalence while at it.

So, what I'm trying to figure out is how syntactically I would define a Delegate that takes 1 to N boolean arguments, such that I avoid violating DRY like this...

```
public delegate bool OneArgFunc(bool arg1);

public delegate bool TwoArgFunc(bool arg1, bool arg2);

public delegate bool ThreeArgFunc(bool arg1, bool arg2, bool arg3);

public delegate bool OuchieThisIsStartingToHurt(bool arg, bool arg, bool arg...);
```

...and I don't believe the below will do it, as "ListOnlyFunc" takes a *list* of type boolean as a single argument--when what I want is a delegate that can accept a boolean function with two boolean arguments, or a function with 1200 boolean arguments.

```
public delegate bool ListOnlyFunc(bool[] args); // Nope!
```

Part of the reason I want to avoid that latter is that I want to be able to extract the argument names from the function, as well (instead of displaying generic indexed arguments). For instance, if I run the below I should see "foo, baz, turkey" in the output window; I don't want to simply get the count of the number of arguments and output an index ("1, 2, 3").

```
public CSharpBoolDelegate MyFunc(bool foo, bool baz, bool turkey)
{
//does things
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IStatementSniffer sniffer = new CSharpFunctionSniffer(myFunc);

        sniffer.printArgs();

    }
}
```

If you have any tips on how I could approach this (or if it is even possible), advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Consider using `MethodInfo`, which allows fetching parameter names and also invoking the function, if you provide an array with the correct number of elements matching the expected number of parameters.

Comment: In my mind the code you provided (`MyFunc`) doesn't logically fit in with the list of delegates you provided. I think you need to flesh out your code a bit more and show how it relates to the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

you can define param method delegate like this

```
 public delegate bool SumParameters(params bool[] values)
```

if you want name of argument than you can make use of dictionary , this solution already suggested by @Rob

```
 public delegate bool SumParameters(Dictionary<string,bool> values)
```

Comment: This still has the issue that he needs the parameter names (`I don't want to simply get the count of the number of arguments and output an index ("1, 2, 3").`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want argument names, it gets a bit messy. Depending on what you want to do, you can write something like this:

```
public void MyFunc(bool? argOne = null, 
              bool? argTwo = null,
              bool? argThree = null,
              bool? argFour = null,
              bool? argFive = null)
{

}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
MyFunc(true);
MyFunc(true, false);
MyFunc(true, false, true);
MyFunc(true, false, true, false);
```

However, this raises some complications. Is this valid, for example?

```
MyFunc(null, true)
```

Here we've only supplied `argTwo`, but it might make sense that you must provide all previous arguments as well (ie. it's not valid to skip an argument).

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
public void MyFunc(Dictionary<string, bool> args)
{

}
```

And call it like this:

```
 MyFunc(new Dictionary<string, bool> { { "arg1", true }, {"arg2", true } });
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get some information about the method then what you need is a method that accepts a `Delegate` as a parameter:

```
public static string MethodSignature(Delegate del) => del.Method.ToString();
```

The downside to this is that a method is *not* a `Delegate` (or a `delegate`) so you'll have to cast to `Func<...>`, `Action<...>` or some other suitable delegate type at the time of the call like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(MethodSignature((Func<bool, bool, bool>)testFunc));
    Console.WriteLine(MethodSignature((Action<bool, bool[]>)testAction));
}

bool testFunc(bool a, bool b) => a || b;

void testAction(bool a, bool[] b) { };
```

Of course if you already have a `delegate` you don't need the cast.

Either way, once you have a `delegate` the parameter names are available:

```
public static string ParameterNames(Delegate del) => 
    string.Join(", ", del.Method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name));
```