# Problem with solving an equation in a logical way

Tags: ruby, math, equation

I was thinking about a way to solve simple equations with simple object orientation. I found a method that appears to works in all cases where the variable is alone. See:

For sample, this equation: `(4 / x + 3) / 2 = 2`
First I convert the equal in a minus operator (`(4 / x + 3) / 2 - 2 = 0`) to equaly everything to zero.
Then I apply all operations in normal precedence order, exactly as if `x` becomes a number. The first one is `4 / x`, I put on stack the operation: `4/` and return x. The next is `x + 3` (remeber that `4 / x` resulted in `x`). The operations goes to the stack (now is `4/ +3`) and returns `x`. Remeating this the final stack will be `4/ +3 /2 -2`. Then I revert all operations in this order:

```
+n   -->  -n
-n   -->  +n
*n   -->  /n
/n   -->  *n
n/   -->  n/
**n  -->  **(1/n)
     (where the missing value of these binary operations is the variable)
```

Now the stack is `4/ -3 *2 +2`. Now I reverse the order and apply all operations to zero:

Stack: `+2 *2 -3 4/`
Operation: `4 / ((0 + 2) * 2 - 3)`

The result is four, the value of `x`.

This is very confuse and complex, but is logical and is easy to make a code in ruby that executes that in any equation:

```
class Variable
  # define all numeric operators to use the stack and return self
end
def solve
  x = Variable.new
  yield(x)
  return x.value
end

x = solve do |x|
  (4 / x + 3) / 2 == 2
end
```

The final interface of this is very cool.

But my problem is that: How to solve `x + x == 4` in this way? In other words, how to add two variable stacks?

Comment: You don't need two variable stacks for this. You need a simplifying stage that changes this to `2x = 4` and then solves for `x`.

Comment: *"I was thinking about a way to solve simple equations with simple object orientation."* - there is something inherently wrong here. You solve this algorithmically (and to an extend procedurally). Instead of focusing on OO (however simple), focus on the algorithmic steps needed here. I mean, **how do you** solve such an equation? What are the steps you use in general? Write them down, and then analyze them for a way to write as an algorithm.

Comment: As Michael said, your stack approach lacks the ability to *simplify* equations. You need a simplification algorithm that takes the original equation and creates a *normalized* one that you can feed into your stack-based process. But then, there are limits since  your original algorithm can only handle equations were the independent variable occurs only once. It cannot handle equations with the variable occurring more than once (as in x^2+x).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression transformation problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757282/expression-transformation-problem)

Comment: @Michael You should make that an answer.

Comment: I've never used Prolog, but would Prolog be better suited to answering this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested I'm making my previous comment an answer:

You don't need two variable stacks for this. You need a simplifying stage that changes this to `2x = 4` and then solves for `x`.

To expand on that, a first step that does some symbolic computation like term rewriting and simplification would be in order. Once you have that, use your current solver (keep in mind what Luis said in his comments though).