# Nested JTrees : Expression tree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying to convert a postfix expression to an expression tree. My method is to have a stack of JTree for the expression tree, a stack of string for paranthesis and a stack of nodes for operators.

Eg postfi `( C ( A B OR ) AND )`

I am able to populate the stacks but when I encounter a  ')' I want to create a new JTree in the JTree stack which will contain the operator stack's pop (operator JTree) as root, and the two expression JTrees (pop the expression stack twice) as children.

When I try to create a new tree, as above, I am unable to add the two popped JTrees to the parent operator JTree. Is there another way to do this? How can I nest 2 JTrees? Please tell me if I am not clear/ need to post code.

Comment: I've not seen parentheses in postfix notation. See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/423898/230513).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to implement that.

Comment: In fact, I found another way to do it. Instead of making them all JTrees, I'm making the type nodes and I have solved the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).