# Groovy - Split string with multiple parentheses matches

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a following string:

'(1:A & ((2:B | 3:C) & (4:D | 5:E))) | (6:F & 7:G)'

and I want to parse them into tree hierarchy object.
1:A, 2:B, 3:C should be in leafs and & or | in roots.
Parentheses are important, so string from example should be converted into:

```
            |
         /    \
        /      \
       &        &
      / \      / \
     /   \    /   \
   1:A    &  6:F  7:G
         / \
        /   \
       /     \      
      |      |
     / \    / \
  2:B 3:C  4:D 5:E
```

I tried to use patter which had split the brackets, but I could not convert the result in a reasonable hierarchy.
I ran out of ideas, maybe some of you will have some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution using regex.

The idea is to recursively parse the input string matching leaf nodes and expressions in paranthesis. Each invokation of the `parse` method will match it's entire input and either return a node with the input value (if it is a leaf) or a node with two sub-nodes that are evaluated recursively (if it matches a pattern of "expression operator expression").

In its current form it requires highly regular input:

- a leaf must be on the form digit:upperCaseCharacter with no parenthesis
- one space between operator and expressions
- an expression is either a leaf or something contained in parenthesis

Whenever the regex matches, all matching groups are collected and null values are removed. There will be 8 non-null groups (since the number of grouping parenthesis are always the same) and the inner groups will always be number 2, 3 and 5, where 3 is the operator and 2 and 5 are the input for the left and right nodes respectively.

The `toString` method simply writes out the expression in polish notation (op ex1 ex2).

```
class Node {
    String value
    Node left, right

    static leaf = /(\d:[A-Z])/
    static op = /([&|])/
    static par = /\((.+)\)/

    static parse(String text) {
        if (text ==~ "^$leaf\$") {
            return new Node(value: text)
        }
        def matcher = text =~ "^($leaf|$par) $op ($leaf|$par)\$"
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            def (l,o,r) = (matcher[0] - null)[2,3,5]
            return new Node(left: parse(l), value: o, right: parse(r))
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Irregular input: $text")
    }

    String toString() {
        left && right ? "$value $left $right" : value
    }
}
```

Example:

```
println Node.parse('1:A')
println Node.parse('1:A & 2:B')
println Node.parse('(1:A & 2:B) | 3:C')
println Node.parse('(1:A & ((2:B | 3:C) & (4:D | 5:E))) | (6:F & 7:G)')
```

Produces the following polish notation output:

```
1:A
& 1:A 2:B
| & 1:A 2:B 3:C
| & 1:A & | 2:B 3:C | 4:D 5:E & 6:F 7:G
```

Comment: Almost everything what I need. I tried to change leaf pattern without success. In my case there could be something some complex than in example. Let's say uuid and word after : ( In case of word I can probably use \w but I stopped on uuid). Whenever I tried to change the regex getting an exception.

Comment: Can you provide an example leaf? If so, I can give it a go.

Comment: 682be428-25af-4a96-b057-0a9f28f40bcf:Sport or 54bc9a00-d030-4e63-9ded-a8c52063802d:Travel ( UUID v4 and word )

Comment: So, instead of matching a digit you want to match many chars with values 0..9, a..f and the hyphen -. Instead of uppercase letter you can match any word with \w+. All in all, this should do the trick: `leaf = /([0-9a-f-]+:\w+)/`

Answer (score 1):

[Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

[Relevant question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423898/postfix-notation-to-expression-tree)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this does it (at least for your example input).

First, I replace all `X:Y` instances with `Leaf` instances, store the Leaf in a cache list and replace the `X:Y` with the index of the Leaf in the cache.

Then, I repeatedly look for `(L O R)` patterns, create a Node instance for it (looking up L and R in the cache), add it to the cache, and replace it with it's cache index in the string.

Then you are left with a String `11 | 9` (or similar), which can be converted into a Node as before.

Hope that explains it.  Might be a more sensible solution to use a proper parser generator if this is for anything serious, or will need extending in the future...

```
import groovy.transform.*

def input = '(1:A & ((2:B | 3:C) & (4:D | 5:E))) | (6:F & 7:G)'

def cache = []

// Remove all X:Y items into a lookup table
input = input.replaceAll( /\w+:\w+/ ) {
  cache << new Leaf( it )
  cache.size() - 1
}

// Then keep finding Nodes filling them with cached values and adding them into the cache
while( input ==~ /.*\(\d+ [&|] \d+\).*/ ) {
    input = input.replaceAll( /\(\d+ [&|] \d+\)/ ) {
        def (left,op,right) = it[ 1..-2 ].tokenize()
        cache << new Node( cache[ left.toInteger() ], op, cache[ right.toInteger() ] )
        cache.size() - 1
    }
}

// Then we're left with "11 | 9", so make the root node
def (left,op,right) = input.tokenize()
def tree = new Node( cache[ left.toInteger() ], op, cache[ right.toInteger() ] )

println tree

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Classes to hold leafs and nodes

@Canonical
class Leaf {
    String value
    String toString( String prefix ) {
        "${prefix}${value}"
    }
}

@TupleConstructor
class Node {
    def left, op, right
    String toString( String prefix ) {
        """${prefix}left:
          |${prefix}${left.toString( prefix + '    ' )}
          |${prefix}op: $op
          |${prefix}right:
          |${prefix}${right.toString( prefix + '    ' )}""".stripMargin()
    }
    String toString() {
        toString( '' )
    }
}
```